# Scaling a Sprite Pygame: must be pygame.surface

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, sprite, scale

code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
block = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
block.image = pygame.image.load('stone.png')
newblock = pygame.transform.scale(block, (64, 64))
newblock.rect = newblock.image.get_rect()
newblock.group = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle(newblock)
newblock.group.draw(screen)
pygame.display.update()
```

When i try to scale the image with pygame.transform.scale it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pygame/program.py", line 8, in <module>
    newblock = pygame.transform.scale(block, (64, 64))
TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not Sprite
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all. The first argument to  `pygame.transform.scale` needs to be a `Surface`, but you pass a `Sprite`.

I guess you want something like:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
img = pygame.image.load('stone.png')

block = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
block.image = pygame.transform.scale(img, (64, 64))
block.rect = block.image.get_rect()

group = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle(block)

while True:
    #TODO: event handling
    group.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```